# How to pass POST data to external site after recaptcha authentication?

Tags: php, forms, recaptcha

I have a form where the action is a script on another website and I need to filter out spam. I have set up recaptcha v2 and changed my form action to point to a local php file which is successfully receiving the response from recaptcha as 'success' or 'fail'. On a 'fail' I use a php header to send the visitor back to the page they came from, but on a 'success' I can't figure out the next step. What is the best way to take my POST data and submit it to the external website's capture.php script?

Comment: I'm still blankly staring at an empty 'if ($response->success)' statement. I can repopulate a new form with the POST data and automatically submit it to the external form handler via javascript but that feels incredibly clumsy and I'm guessing there must be a better way, perhaps with curl?

Comment: You could post the data with [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).  What you do after that though depends on what the remote site does after you post the data.  Does it just take the data and give you a response while the user stays on your site?  Or does the user get redirected to the external site?  If the latter, you'll have to parse the response headers from curl and redirect the user yourself.

Comment: After the data is posted to the external site it redirects the visitor back to the url contained in _POST[$origin] with ?success=true appended. If cURL is the best for this 'file-in-the-middle' scenario I'll take a look at that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You do not give us a lot to go on but since it is 2019 I will assume that you want to talk to another sites via an API. At the very least you want to call a specific script that you know if there and can receive calls from you (and is hopefully a bit secure).

You have to make a request to that site "just like" a browser would. Most servers come with CURL to make a request. PHP has a function called `curl_exec()` check that out [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php)

If you are going to be heavily relying on making calls to other resources outside of your site it would be smarter to let someone else do the heavy lifting for you and pull in a third-party vendor library. One I have use but am not endorsing as solidly vetted is GuzzleHTTP [doc](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/). They basically wrap curl for you and give you a standard request response structure.

Answer (score 0):

## How I understand your real problem

> I have a form where the action is a script on another website and I need to filter out spam.

Based on this I assumed my entire response that your real problem is to not allow bots, automated scripts to submit your form, thus my reply does not show how you can submit the POST data to another website, but instead shows you the options to tackle what seems to be your real issue.

## The form action redirection doesn't solve the issue

> changed my form action to point to a local php file which is successfully receiving the response from recaptcha as 'success' or 'fail'. On a 'fail' I use a php header to send the visitor back to the page they came from, but on a 'success' I can't figure out the next step.

This approach can be easily faked by any attacker. they can just hit F12 in the browser to see how you make the request to this php script that you use to validate the reCaptcha v2 and then automate the process, thus bypassing easily your protection.

So the approach you are taking to tackle the problem of only allow a human to submit a form will not work.

## Recommended to use reCaptcha V3

> I have set up recaptcha v2

I would recommend to use [Google reCaptcha V3](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html) that will run in the background without needing any user interaction and will return a score from 0 to 1, where towards 1 it means that is an human using the page, otherwise is an automated tool.

Google quote:

> We are excited to introduce reCAPTCHA v3, which helps you detect abusive traffic on your website without any user friction. It returns a score based on the interactions with your website and provides you more flexibility to take appropriate actions.

#### Important

Include reCaptcha V3 in all pages of your website so that Google can learn about the user and its behaviours in order to give you a more confident score about if its a human or a bot. Remember that once it does not prompt the user for interaction it does not affect the user experience in any page of your site.

Validate always the reCaptcha V3 score in the back-end, in order to know if is a human or a bot doing it and block accordingly. You may even want to add this check into other back-end endpoints that may have sensitive data that you don't want to be scraped.

Example response from Google API for a server side reCaptcha V3 validation, as per [Google docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3):

```json
{
  "success": true|false,      // whether this request was a valid reCAPTCHA token for your site
  "score": number             // the score for this request (0.0 - 1.0)
  "action": string            // the action name for this request (important to verify)
  "challenge_ts": timestamp,  // timestamp of the challenge load (ISO format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ)
  "hostname": string,         // the hostname of the site where the reCAPTCHA was solved
  "error-codes": [...]        // optional
}
```

## Further Protection

#### Cross-Site Request Forgery more known as CSRF

If you are using a framework it should have already built-in protection for this, just read their documents on forms. Otherwise read the [OWASP CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) description on the attack and the [OWASP CSRF Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) to learn how to defend against it.

OWASP quote:

> Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) is an attack that forces an end user to execute unwanted actions on a web application in which they're currently authenticated.

#### Cross Site Scripting also known as XSS

For a description of the attack read the [OWASP XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) attack description and then head over to the [OWASP Prevention Chaeta Sheat](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) to see how to defend against it. Once more if you use a framework it should already have tooling in place to help you preventing XSS attacks.

OWASP quote:

> Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attacks are a type of injection, in which malicious scripts are injected into otherwise benign and trusted websites. XSS attacks occur when an attacker uses a web application to send malicious code, generally in the form of a browser side script, to a different end user.

## Continue to use reCaptcha V2

So if you want to continue to use reCaptcha V2, just let it work as usual:

- blocking the user to click the form submit button until it passes all the Google challenges.
- pointing the form to the original php script that handles the form submission and have it checking the reCaptcha V2 in server side.

Example verification response from Google API, as per [Google docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify):

```json
{
  "success": true|false,
  "challenge_ts": timestamp,  // timestamp of the challenge load (ISO format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ)
  "hostname": string,         // the hostname of the site where the reCAPTCHA was solved
  "error-codes": [...]        // optional
}
```

Please bear in mind that reCaptcha V2 can be bypassed, just search Google for `recaptcha v2 bypass` to see how many services exist for this, that will allow attackers to continue hitting the script in an automated way.

Comment: This is all well and good, but in no way addresses OP's actual question

Comment: It addresses in the sense he should not do the approach he is taking, that is not secure and ultimately does not solve the issue he is trying to solve, that is ensuring that only humans submit the form.

Comment: The issue the user is describing is how to get the data from their site to another site for processing. While yes there could be concerns of other issues you do not answer the main question.

Comment: Is current issue with the post data is just a stone in his way on the wrong path to solve the root of the problem. What I mean is that the OPs question about the post data doesn't reflect his real issue and in my opinion we have enough information in his question to see that the real issue is not posting the data to another site, but instead protecting the form submission from being used by spammers, aka automated scripts. So teaching him how to post the data to another site is helping him to keep in the wrong direction to solve is real problem.

Comment: I can change v2 to v3 but I'm still in the same situation. I don't know how to use recaptcha on a web form that sends the post data to a script running on another website. If I change the form action to a local file where I perform recaptcha verification, I don't know how to pass that information from the local file to the remote script.

Comment: the best and secure approach is to always submit your data to the same backend of your website so that you atre alwasy in control of the flow and can apply security controls. Now in this backend you can apply the recaptcha server side verification and then you can use GuzzleHttp as @nerdlyist suggested to send the post data to the other site, their docs have plenty of examples in how you can do it.